# Trying to modify read-only DataSet field

Tags: c++, ado, c++builder

I use C++ Builder 6.0

I use TADODataSet execute following SQL statement:

```
SELECT Id, SUM(Saldo) AS Saldo 
FROM Table 
GROUP BY Id
```

I use this DataSet only for reporting. No need update date back to database.
When I try to modify field "Saldo"

```
adospCard->Edit();
adospCard->FieldByName("Saldo")->AsFloat=0.0;
adospCard->Post();
```

I get error:
Field 'Saldo' cannot be modified.
I add this line

```
adospCard->FieldByName("Saldo")->ReadOnly=false;
```

and error no more occurred, but field 'Saldo' has not changed.

```
adospCard->Edit();
//adospCard->FieldByName("Saldo")->AsFloat=1536.5
adospCard->FieldByName("Saldo")->AsFloat=0.0;
//adospCard->FieldByName("Saldo")->AsFloat=0
adospCard->Post();
//adospCard->FieldByName("Saldo")->AsFloat=1536.5
```

Howe to change ‘Saldo’ field value?

Comment: Why are you trying to change it? It is actually just a value computed by the db, not a "real" field.

Comment: I understand that ‘saldo’ is not real field, but client required to change this value on some reports when Id is …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a calculated field to your dataset.
2. Calculate the right value for Saldo
   in this calculated field (you can
   use Saldo as source for it if you
   want to)
3. display this calculated field in your report in
   stead of the Saldo field.

**Edit:**
*For examples of how to add calculated fields, see for instance [here](http://www.componentace.com/calculated-field-delphi.htm), [here](http://www.delphitricks.com/source-code/database/add_field_to_table_at_runtime.html) and [here](http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+III+Delphi+Database-Oriented+Architectures/Chapter+13+Delphi+s+Database+Architecture/The+Fields+of+a+Dataset/).*

--jeroen

Comment: Th.
How to add calculated field when dataset are opened?

Answer (score 1):

As ldsandon said, you cannot modify the "Saldo" field as it is computed.
If you need to set the value to zero when Id is "something" you are better off doing it in your query. The best approach depends on the criteria for setting the value to zero.

Or, save the results of the original query in a temp table then modify that before returning the results to the report.

Finally, what reporting tool are you using? Can that do the "Saldo = 0" change when rendering the report?

Comment: Query result (report) is displayed in grid. Saldo=0 is just simple example. Real report is much complex, with 15-20 calculated fields, and very complex logic which calculated field will be changed, and this logic depend by user input…
Is not possible do this on rendering report or, SQL statement.

Comment: In which case why not load the results from the query in to a data structure which you *can* modify and then apply the necessary changes to the values?

Answer (score 1):

Consider storing your result in a ClientDataset - if you can be assured the result isn't too large.

I don't use "TADODataSet" so the following may not apply :)...

When I do the same (or similar) using my DB of choice (i.e. Advantage Database Server) I would use the INTO clause, albeit, with a TSQLQuery component (with the RequestLive property enabled).  For example:

SELECT Id, SUM(Saldo) AS Saldo  INTO #TempTable FROM Table  GROUP BY Id